# Set legend description as color representated

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, legend

Im plotting a scatter figure of my datasheet. It has values of KW generated by different buildings in a period of time.

Every colour of the scatter represents a building.

I don't know what I have to do to plot the legend with the buildings and the colours on the figure.

This is my plotting code:

```py
def plot_data(dataframe, x_values, y_values):
    plt.scatter(dataframe[x_values], dataframe[y_values], alpha=0.5, c=dataframe['ID_SEDE'])
    plt.title('Scatter plot ' + y_values)
    plt.xlabel(x_values)
    plt.ylabel(y_values)
    plt.legend(T_MEDIDAS_CO_DROP_FILTERED['ID_SEDE'].unique())
    plt.show()
```

the figure only shows my first ID_SEDE as blue point on the legend:

[image: Scatter Plot Results]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

My bad about coding. I've made a loop in order to "loc" df values of every building and add it to the scatter:

```
buildings = dataframe['ID_SEDE'].unique()
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15), dpi=80)
for building in buildings:
    dataframe_build = dataframe.loc[(dataframe['ID_SEDE'] == building)]
    plt.scatter(dataframe_build[x_values], dataframe_build[y_values], alpha=0.5, label=('SEDE ' + str(sede)))
    plt.title('Scatter plot ' + y_values)
    plt.xlabel(x_values)
    plt.xlabel(y_values)
    plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here is the output:
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UW4Q.png)